# On Mobile reboot android notification not working in Unity

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, notifications

This is BroadcastReceiver extended to RebootManager. The problem is on mobile reboot or restart the notifications are not displayed. i have all three Boot reset calls enabled in intent filter action but i don't see what is wrong. it will be nice if someone can help with this code. the app displays the notification if the mobile is not rebooted but on reboot the mobile loses data for notification.

```
import java.util.Iterator;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;

public class RebootManager extends BroadcastReceiver
{
    public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {
        for (final int id : Storage.GetNotificationIds(context)) {
            final NotificationParams params = Storage.GetNotification(context, id);
            if (params != null) {
                Controller.SetNotification(context, params);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
using System;
using UnityEngine;

namespace Assets.SimpleAndroidNotifications
{
    public class NotificationExample : MonoBehaviour
    {
        
        public void ScheduleSimple()
        {
            NotificationManager.Send(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(120), "Simple notification", "Customize icon and color", new Color(1, 0.3f, 0.15f));
        }

        public void ScheduleNormal()
        {
            NotificationManager.SendWithAppIcon(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(120), "Notification", "Notification with app icon", new Color(0, 0.6f, 1), NotificationIcon.Message);
        }
        public void ScheduleNormal2()
        {
            NotificationManager.SendWithAppIcon(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(120), "Notification", "Notification with app icon", new Color(0, 0.6f, 1), NotificationIcon.Message);
        }
        public void ScheduleCustom()
        {
            var notificationParams = new NotificationParams
            {
                Id = UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, int.MaxValue),
                Delay = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(120),
                Title = "Custom notification",
                Message = "Message",
                Ticker = "Ticker",
                Sound = true,
                Vibrate = true,
                Light = true,
                SmallIcon = NotificationIcon.Heart,
                SmallIconColor = new Color(0, 0.5f, 0),
                LargeIcon = "app_icon"
            };

            NotificationManager.SendCustom(notificationParams);
        }

        public void CancelAll()
        {
            NotificationManager.CancelAll();
        }

    }
}
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.hippogames.simpleandroidnotifications"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15" />
    <application android:largeHeap="true" android:allowBackup="true" android:directBootAware="true"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:debuggable="true">
        <activity android:name="com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity" android:launchMode="singleTask"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>        
            <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.UnityActivity" android:value="true" />
        </activity> 
        <receiver android:name="com.hippogames.simpleandroidnotifications.Controller" />
        <receiver android:name="com.hippogames.simpleandroidnotifications.RebootManager" 
            android:directBootAware="true"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.LOCKED_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

```
using System;
using UnityEngine;

#if UNITY_ANDROID && !UNITY_EDITOR

using System.Linq;

#endif

namespace Assets.SimpleAndroidNotifications
{
    public static class NotificationManager
    {
        #if UNITY_ANDROID && !UNITY_EDITOR

        private const string FullClassName = "com.hippogames.simpleandroidnotifications.Controller";
        private const string MainActivityClassName = "com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity";

        #endif

        /// <summary>
        /// Schedule simple notification without app icon.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="smallIcon">List of build-in small icons: notification_icon_bell (default), notification_icon_clock, notification_icon_heart, notification_icon_message, notification_icon_nut, notification_icon_star, notification_icon_warning.</param>
        public static int Send(TimeSpan delay, string title, string message, Color smallIconColor, NotificationIcon smallIcon = 0)
        {
            return SendCustom(new NotificationParams
            {
                Id = UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, int.MaxValue),
                Delay = delay,
                Title = title,
                Message = message,
                Ticker = message,
                Sound = true,
                Vibrate = true,
                Light = true,
                SmallIcon = smallIcon,
                SmallIconColor = smallIconColor,
                LargeIcon = ""
            });
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Schedule notification with app icon.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="smallIcon">List of build-in small icons: notification_icon_bell (default), notification_icon_clock, notification_icon_heart, notification_icon_message, notification_icon_nut, notification_icon_star, notification_icon_warning.</param>
        public static int SendWithAppIcon(TimeSpan delay, string title, string message, Color smallIconColor, NotificationIcon smallIcon = 0)
        {
            return SendCustom(new NotificationParams
            {
                Id = UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, int.MaxValue),
                Delay = delay,
                Title = title,
                Message = message,
                Ticker = message,
                Sound = true,
                Vibrate = true,
                Light = true,
                SmallIcon = smallIcon,
                SmallIconColor = smallIconColor,
                LargeIcon = "app_icon"
            });
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Schedule customizable notification.
        /// </summary>
        public static int SendCustom(NotificationParams notificationParams)
        {
            #if UNITY_ANDROID && !UNITY_EDITOR

            var p = notificationParams;
            var delay = (long) p.Delay.TotalMilliseconds;

            new AndroidJavaClass(FullClassName).CallStatic("SetNotification", p.Id, delay, p.Title, p.Message, p.Ticker,
                p.Sound ? 1 : 0, p.Vibrate ? 1 : 0, p.Light ? 1 : 0, p.LargeIcon, GetSmallIconName(p.SmallIcon), ColotToInt(p.SmallIconColor), MainActivityClassName);

            #else
            
            Debug.LogWarning("Simple Android Notifications are not supported for current platform. Build and play this scene on android device!");

            #endif

            return notificationParams.Id;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Cancel notification by id.
        /// </summary>
        public static void Cancel(int id)
        {
            #if UNITY_ANDROID && !UNITY_EDITOR

            new AndroidJavaClass(FullClassName).CallStatic("CancelScheduledNotification", id);

            #endif
        }
                
        /// <summary>
        /// Cancel all notifications.
        /// </summary>
        public static void CancelAll()
        {
            #if UNITY_ANDROID && !UNITY_EDITOR

            new AndroidJavaClass(FullClassName).CallStatic("CancelAllScheduledNotifications");

            #endif
        }

        private static int ColotToInt(Color color)
        {
            var smallIconColor = (Color32) color;
            
            return smallIconColor.r * 65536 + smallIconColor.g * 256 + smallIconColor.b;
        }

        private static string GetSmallIconName(NotificationIcon icon)
        {
            return "anp_" + icon.ToString().ToLower();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you are missing `RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED` permission in your manifest, by defaut android deletes notifications after boot. This should give you the desired result.

Here is the documentation how to do this if you are using the same asset:

https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.mobile.notifications@1.3/manual/Settings.html

Comment: in line no 9 you can see i am using `RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED` in my Manifest.xml file.is there any where else i need to use it?